# type JSON data with Record<> and check whether key exists

Tags: json, typescript

My backend provides a JSON object that maps id strings to data:

```
{
  "asdo2q" : 253,
  "s398dd" : 132,
  ...
}
```

As far as I can see, the corresponding Typescript type is a [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt). Since an id might not exist, I'm using:

```
let data: Record<string, number | undefined> = {
    'asdf': 1
};
```

Now I need to process this data and need to check whether a key exists:

```
const id = 'asdf';
if (id in data) {
    const id_data = data[id];
    console.log(id_data + 1); // compiler says it might be undefined
}
```

The compiler support seems to be much better for other patterns. So I'm wondering: Is this the correct way to type my backend response?

Answer (score 3):

that's expected because `id in data` doesn't do anything with `id_data = data[id]`. `id` can be in `data` but its value still can be `undefined`.

You need to assert value itself.

```js
const data: Record<string, number | undefined> = {
  "asdo2q" : 253,
  "s398dd" : 132,
}

const id = 'asdf';
const id_data = data[id];
if (id_data !== undefined) {
    console.log(id_data + 1); // now it works
}
```